# How to escape a C# regular expression in the correct way?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, escaping

This is my regex in plain form:

```
<tr>[\s]+?<td class="filePathActiv"[\w\W]+?<div class="Overflow">[\s]*?(?<name>[\w\W]+?)&nbsp[\w\W]+?\(wygasa (?<wygasa>[\d\s\-\:\s]+)\)[\w\W]+?class="fileDown"[\w\W]+?<a href="(?<address>[\w\W]+?)">[\w\W]+?<td width="[\d]+?">(?<sizeMB>[\d\.]+?) MB</td>[\w\W]+?<input [\w\W]+? name="(?<path>[\w\W]+?)" [\w\W]+? value="(?<value>[\w\W]+?)"[\w\W]+?/>
```

How should I escape this regex? I tried like that but it's not working:

```
new Regex("<tr>[\\s]+?<td class=\"filePathActiv\"[\\w\\W]+?<div class=\"Overflow\">[\\s]*?(?<name>[\\w\\W]+?)&nbsp[\\w\\W]+?\\(wygasa (?<date>[\\d\\s\\-\\:\\s]+)\\)[\\w\\W]+?class=\"fileDown\"[\\w\\W]+?<a href=\"(?<address>[\\w\\W]+?)\">[\\w\\W]+?<td width=\"[\\d]+?\">(?<sizeMB>[\\d\\.]+?) MB</td>[\\w\\W]+?<input [\\w\\W]+? name=\"(?<path>[\\w\\W]+?)\" [\\w\\W]+? value=\"(?<value>[\\w\\W]+?)\"[\\w\\W]+?/>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should put it in a `@"..."` string.
Then, all you need to do is replace every `"` with `""`.

Comment: Also, check out the '.net' button at http://regexhero.net/tester/.  If you paste in your regex in plain form, it will generate C# code for you using the @"...".  (Another user just pointed this out to me in another thread.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `Regex.Escape()` method.